# How can I show multiple plot with scrollbar in a custom Dash layout?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have the following synthetic data set and I use the following layout (script1.py):

```py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, dash_table
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import os, dash, random
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
import base64

# create the dummy data
hour_timetable = [i for i in range(24)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-01 23:59:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 2) for n in range(72)]})
df['HOUR'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour
df['MINUTE'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
df['DBP'] = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=72)
df['DBP2'] = np.random.uniform(45, 75, size=72)
df['SBP'] = np.random.uniform(110, 180, size=72)
df['SBP2'] = np.random.uniform(90, 130, size=72)
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
df['seconds'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour * 60 + df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute

# Compute areas and colors
hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24 * 60, endpoint=False)

app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Container(
        [
            html.Br(),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown', options=df.ID.unique(), value=df.columns[0]),
            html.Br(),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H2('Single inspection graph'),
                        dcc.Graph(id='single_inspection', style={'height': '80vh'})
                    ],
                    width=3,
                ),
                dbc.Col([
                    html.H2('Line plot'),
                    dcc.Graph(id='line_plot', style={'height': '36vh'}),
                    html.H2('Data table'),
                    html.Div(id='data_table_container', style={'height': '36vh', 'overflow': 'scroll'})
                ], width=5),
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H2('Multi inspection graph'),
                        dcc.Graph(id='multi_inspection', style={'height': '80vh'})
                    ],
                    width=4,
                    style={'height': '100%'},
                )
            ], className='vh-100', justify='start')
        ],
        style={
            "background-color": "green",
            "padding": "0 1rem 0 1rem",
            "margin-left": "0",
            "margin-right": "0",
        },
        fluid=True
    )
],
)


@app.callback(
    Output('single_inspection', 'figure'),
    Output('line_plot', 'figure'),
    Output('multi_inspection', 'figure'),
    Output('data_table_container', 'children'),
    Input('dropdown', 'value'),
)

def first_callback(dropdown):
    single = px.scatter(df[df.ID==dropdown], x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"])
    line = px.line(df[df.ID==dropdown], x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"],
                         facet_col_wrap=2,
                         facet_row_spacing=0.1,
                         facet_col_spacing=0.09)
    multi = px.line(df[df.ID==dropdown], x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"])
    table =  dash_table.DataTable(
                id='datatable-advanced-filtering',
                columns=[
                    {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in df[df.ID==dropdown].columns
                    # omit the id column
                    if i != 'id'
                ],
                data=df[df.ID==dropdown].to_dict('records'),
                editable=True,
                page_action='native',
                page_size=10,
                filter_action="native"
            )

    return single, line, multi, table

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Besides, I have the following radial chart which is created from same synthetic data as above (script2.py):

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
import base64

app = dash.Dash()

# create the dummy data
hour_timetable = [i for i in range(24)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-01 23:59:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 2) for n in range(72)]})
df['HOUR'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour
df['MINUTE'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute

# Compute areas and colors
hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24 * 60, endpoint=False)

charts = []
for i in range(5):
    df['DBP'] = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=72)
    df['DBP2'] = np.random.uniform(45, 75, size=72)
    df['SBP'] = np.random.uniform(110, 180, size=72)
    df['SBP2'] = np.random.uniform(90, 130, size=72)
    df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
    df = df[(df.ID == 1)]

    df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
    df['seconds'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour * 60 + df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute

    r = df.SBP.tolist()
    r2 = df.SBP2.tolist()
    s = df.DBP.tolist()
    s2 = df.DBP2.tolist()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})

    ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], r, color='red', label='SBP')
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], r2, color='red', label='SBP2')
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], s, color='blue', label='DBP')
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], s2, color='blue', label='DBP2')
    ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df['seconds']], r, r2, interpolate=True, color='red', alpha=0.3)
    ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df['seconds']], s, s2, interpolate=True, color='blue', alpha=0.3)
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
    ax.set_xticklabels(range(24))
    ax.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.1), fontsize=8)
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 180)
    ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2.0)

    buffer = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buffer, format='png')
    buffer.seek(0)

    image_string = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode()

    charts.append(html.Div([
        html.H3(f'Radial Chart {i + 1}'),
        html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,' + image_string)
    ]))

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Radial Charts'),
    dcc.Markdown('''
    ### Radial Charts

    Here are 5 radial charts generated using Matplotlib:
    '''),
    *charts
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**I expect to integrate/show radial charts in (script2.py) in my layout (script1.py),specifically in the Single Inspection Graph Column** To do so, I tried the following code, but it does not work. Can you help me to figure out how to do it? My attempt is:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import os
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
import base64

from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

# Create the dummy data
hour_timetable = [i for i in range(24)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-01 23:59:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 2) for n in range(72)]})
df['HOUR'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour
df['MINUTE'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
df['DBP'] = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=72)
df['DBP2'] = np.random.uniform(45, 75, size=72)
df['SBP'] = np.random.uniform(110, 180, size=72)
df['SBP2'] = np.random.uniform(90, 130, size=72)
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time

df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
df['seconds'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour * 60 + df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
# Compute areas and colors
hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24 * 60, endpoint=False)

# Read the CSV data
path_to_input_directory = 'C:/Users/oezmenma/Desktop/ABMP Full dataset/Dataset 1'
path_to_input_file = 'ckd_and_healthy_498.csv'
# df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_to_input_directory, path_to_input_file), sep=',',
#                  parse_dates=['DATE_TIME'], infer_datetime_format=True, low_memory=False)

@app.callback(
    Output('single_inspection', 'figure'),
    Output('line_plot', 'figure'),
    Output('multi_inspection', 'figure'),
    Output('data_table_container', 'children'),
    Input('dropdown', 'value'),
)
def update_graphs(dropdown):
    # Generate the radial chart
    df_filtered = df[df.ID == dropdown]
    r = df_filtered['SBP'].tolist()
    r2 = df_filtered['SBP2'].tolist()
    s = df_filtered['DBP'].tolist()
    s2 = df_filtered['DBP2'].tolist()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df_filtered['seconds']], r, color='red', label='SBP')
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df_filtered['seconds']], r2, color='red', label='SBP2')
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df_filtered['seconds']], s, color='blue', label='DBP')
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df_filtered['seconds']], s2, color='blue', label='DBP2')
    ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df_filtered['seconds']], r, r2, interpolate=True, color='red', alpha=0.3)
    ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df_filtered['seconds']], s, s2, interpolate=True, color='blue', alpha=0.3)
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
    ax.set_xticklabels(range(24))
    ax.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.1), fontsize=8)
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 180)
    ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2.0)

    buffer = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buffer, format='png')
    buffer.seek(0)
    image_string = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode()

    single_fig = {
        'data': [],
        'layout': {
            'images': [
                {
                    'source': 'data:image/png;base64,' + image_string,
                    'xref': 'x',
                    'yref': 'y',
                    'x': 0,
                    'y': 0,
                    'sizex': 1,
                    'sizey': 1,
                    'sizing': 'stretch',
                    'layer': 'below',
                }
            ],
            'xaxis': {'visible': False},
            'yaxis': {'visible': False},
        }
    }

    line_fig = px.line(df_filtered, x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"],
                       facet_col_wrap=2, facet_row_spacing=0.1, facet_col_spacing=0.09)

    multi_fig = px.line(df_filtered, x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"])

    # Generate the data table
    data_table = dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-advanced-filtering',
        columns=[
            {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True}
            for i in df_filtered.columns if i != 'id'
        ],
        data=df_filtered.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        page_action='native',
        page_size=10,
        filter_action="native"
    )

    return single_fig, line_fig, multi_fig, data_table


app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Container(
        [
            html.Br(),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown', options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in df.ID.unique()],
                         value=df.columns[0]),
            html.Br(),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H2('Single Inspection Graph'),
                        dcc.Graph(id='single_inspection', style={'height': '80vh'})
                    ],
                    width=3,
                ),
                dbc.Col([
                    html.H2('Line Plot'),
                    dcc.Graph(id='line_plot', style={'height': '36vh'}),
                    html.H2('Data Table'),
                    html.Div(id='data_table_container', style={'height': '36vh', 'overflow': 'scroll'})
                ], width=5),
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H2('Multi Inspection Graph'),
                        dcc.Graph(id='multi_inspection', style={'height': '80vh'})
                    ],
                    width=4,
                    style={'height': '100%'},
                )
            ], className='vh-100', justify='start')
        ],
        style={
            "background-color": "green",
            "padding": "0 1rem 0 1rem",
            "margin-left": "0",
            "margin-right": "0",
        },
        fluid=True
    ),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```